# MPAndroidChart: setMaxVisibleValueCount(int count) doesn't work in Combined Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have 12 bar data entries and I need to display only 5 bar initially, which mean that rest of the bar should be visible on scroll. Yes, in BarGraph I can achieve this. But in Combine chart this method is not working. Is that intended.? Am I missing anything.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to see without an example, but there are a couple of potential issues that I have experienced. Note I have only used line graphs, but it may be a similar issue?

First ensure that you are setting the chart setVisibleXRangeMaximum **after** setting the data. As per the documentation:

> Please note that all methods modifying the viewport need to be called
>   on the Chart after setting data.

For example with the following code I get what I want:

```
private CombinedChart mChart;
....
mChart.setData(data);
// NB > 100 entries
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
```

[image]

Secondly, in my app I have a single chart that can display different data sets, where I have a maximum of 10 entries displayed (as per code above). When I cycle between chartA (100 entries), chartB (6 entries) and chartC (3 entries) charts B & C display a heavily zoomed in view. If I correct the zoom in either B or C and not display chartA, then both B&C display correcly. As soon as I display chartA again, the zoom on both B&C gets muddled up.

So this again could be your problem with it "not working".

To fix this, when the number of data points for a chart is below the setVisibleXRangeMaximum, remove the limitation eg:

```
mChart.setData(data);
if (data.getEntryCount() > 10) {
   mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
}
else {
   mChart.fitScreen();
}
```

I am not sure yet if this is a known issue in mpandroidchart yet, but I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

According to PhilJay [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2086)

The way I see it is that you are confusing "maxVisibleCount" with "visibleXRange".

maxVisibleCount: Controls the number of labels that are drawn until drawing of labels (only) stops.
visibleXRange: Controls the maximum number of visible entries on the chart area. Zooming out further than the visibleXRange is not possible.